# Dependency Isolation and Declaration in PHP

Tags: php, dependency-management

What's the best way to achieve complete [dependency declaration and isolation](http://12factor.net/dependencies) in a PHP web app? I already know about [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/), but that's only the declaration part and I don't think it goes far enough. I'd like to include as much of the following as I can: PHP extensions (e.g. mcrypt, imagick, apc), the php.ini config and configs for extensions, PECL packages, and ideally even my Apache config files. Is there something like Ruby's `bundle exec` for PHP?

Comment: I think chef might be a better approach for your PHP extensions and environment

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe take a look at [PHP_CompatInfo](http://php5.laurent-laville.org/compatinfo/).

This won't take care of reporting the information in any config files but it will tell you what your PHP code needs to run.

Answer (score 0):

Composer's alternative to Bundler's `bundle exec` is `composer exec`. Check out the docs: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#exec

Comment: This does not isolate dependencies, it just lets the composer-installed binaries overwrite system binaries. But anything else that's installed on the system will still be accessible. Also, any extensions will be present, even if they are not required by composer.json.

Comment: I agree that `composer exec` will not isolate from installed extensions.

Do I understand correctly that by «anything else that's installed on the system» you mean that there is still a way to shelling out to the system's environment?

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool which allows to distribute your PHP application based on symfony2 via debian package system. See https://github.com/mjollnir/sf2debpkg